# how to get elements from multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have written some code in php. I have below array, but I can't get the year.

How do I get the year from array i.e the values `1891, 1908, 1916, 1918`?

```
$data = array( 
    1891 => [
        'year' => 
            [0 => 'ABC'],
        'count' =>1
    ],
    1908 => [
        'year' => 
            [0 => 'ABC'],
        'count' => 1
    ],
    1916 => [
        'year' => 
            [0 => 'XYZ'],
        'count' => 1
    ],
    1918 => [
        'year' => 
            [0 => 'PQR'],
        'count' => 1
    ],
    1923 => [
        'year' => 
            [0 => 'LMN'],
        'count' => 1
     ]

    );
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @epodax 
foreach($groups as $row) {
   echo $groups[$row];
  }

Comment: How about just using `array_keys()`

Comment: `foreach($groups as $year => $row) { echo $year } `

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `array` you provided:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $key // This will contain the year
    $value // This will contain the associated aray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reconstructed the array, and it is a true array of arrays (with some arrays thrown in).  Overall, I totally advise against using such a complex data structure without either simplifying or turning it into an object, because it doesn't lend itself well to consumption.

Simplify simplify simplify!

That being said, here is a way to utilize the final data:

```
foreach($data as $num_year=>$info){
    $letters = $info['year'][0]; // or
    $letters = reset($info['year']); // reset gets first element numbered or associative
    $count = $info['count'];
    echo $num_year.' '.$letters.' '.$count;
}
```

See it run on the cleaned-up and reconstructed array with valid output here:
http://ideone.com/b9Fg6V

Comment: @Nitin Karale if you want only those numbers this is correct solution for you and if you want the array inside the years, you can use array_column.I guess you can use array_map() , you should try.